# How to avoid subscribe in subscribe in case of different computaion contexts

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I wrote a program, which receive messages from socket io, and than play media file. So when program receives next message, media player stops and play another. I implemented `SocketIO` message stream as `Observable<String>` and `MediaPlayer` as `Complatable`. So code contains "subscribe in subscribe":

```
class Main {

    Disposable d = null;

    public void start() {    
        ScoketIO.connect("localhost:9000").subscribe(event -> {
            if (d != null)
                d.dispose();
            d = MediaPlayer.play(event).subscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe there is way to avoid "subscribe in subscribe" ? Also good to remove all nullables and make code more "functional"

**upd**

Seems like `switchMap` worked for that simple example:

```
ScoketIO.connect("localhost:9000")
                .switchMapCompletable(event -> MediaPlayer.play(event))
                .subscribe();
```

media player disposed(stop playing) when new event comes. But in case of failure in media player all chain will fail - socket connection too, but it doesn't. Adding `retry` to media player also trigger reconnection. What does'it mean "different computaion contexts".

Comment: why do you have to dispose `MediaPlayer.play`? Is it only completing after the event is played fully?

Comment: would it be possible to make a Completable `MediaPlayer.stop` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you can build a Completable stop method in MediaPlayer you could do:

```
        SocketIO.connect("localhost:9000")
                .flatMapCompletable(event ->
                        MediaPlayer.stop()
                                .andThen(MediaPlayer.play(event))
                ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Disposing media player means stop player. `play` return "cold" Complatable. So introducing `stop` just make media player api not reactive. I want to compose two reactive api.